# Pointers Cannot read image data

Tags: c, pointers, image-processing

I'm trying to read the pixel data from a high-end digital camera. The image size is 320 * 256 pixels and is 2 bytes in size.

```
Int8* ImageBuffer = (Int8 *) malloc(320 * 256 * 2); 
Int32 result = imgGrab ((void **)&ImageBuffer);
```

The above code reads an image but Im not sure how I get at the pixel data.

I've tried the following;

```
WORD* myImage = (WORD*)malloc(320*256*2);
memcpy (myImage, ImageBuffer, 320*256*2 );
```

So I did this to convert to 8bit ImageBuffer to 16bit because each pixel is 2 bytes.
I think I'm on the right track, however the data Im getting in myImage is not right. It is mainly zeros and contains negative numbers.

I'm wondering if I'm getting confused since the 2nd parameter to imgGrab is a pointer to a pointer.
The manual describes the 2nd parameter as a "pointer to a pointer to an area of memory in which to store the image"

So is this function doing what I think it is doing ie. copying the pixel data of the image to myImage?

```
memcpy (myImage, ImageBuffer, 320*256*2 );
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: “The image size is 320 * 256 pixels and is 2 bytes in size.” The quality must be horrible.

Comment: "contains negative numbers" -- is this a 16-bit grayscale or a 15- or 16-bit RGB image? At the very least it suggests you should be using unsigned storage (and read the documentation on your camera for the exact data format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, *pointer to a pointer* is your hint that you do *not* need to allocate this memory. You need to pass a pointer to `imgGrab`, and `imgGrab` will actually make it point to the buffer it has allocated. So you simply have a memory leak there. And also, yo don't need `memcpy` and additional buffer to do this kind of cast. Should be something like this:

```
WORD* myImage = 0;
Int32 result = imgGrab ((void **)&myImage );
```

However, what you did there should have yielded the same result in your `myImage` buffer, so there probably is something else going wrong there, outside of your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. That looks better. I don't get the negative numbers now , just all zeros. I'll check my code again.